# undefined data error on page reload Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm currently developing a universal app using Nuxt.js, the data on most of the pages is retrieved from an API using a fetch hook as well as vuex store. I started noticing errors on page reload/refresh and sometimes when I visit a page from the navbar. The page error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

where data is an object retrieved from an API. I have searched around the internet for this and found it has something to do with data not being loaded or page rendering whilst the data is not fully retrieved. i have found a work around by using a v-if on my template to check if the data is set then display the contents. my question is if there is a way to achieve this, i have tried using the async/await keywords but it doesn't help and i feel like the v-if method is not the best way to handle it.

edit: solved by using $fetchState.pending when using fetch()

Comment: could you show us the error please? in the console you see usually where the error appears

Comment: I have managed to solved the error with the $fetchState.pending thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If in your template you display right away the data you retrieve from the API, then indeed using the v-if is the right way to do.

If you are using the new `fetch()` hook, then in your template you can use `$fetchState.pending` to check if the loading has finished, for example:

```
<div v-if="$fetchState.pending"> 
 <p> Content is loading... </p>
</div>

<div v-else>
 <p> Content has loaded! {{data}}</p>
</div>

<script>
 export default{
  data(){
   return{
    data: null
   }
  }

  async fetch(){
   this.data = await getSomeAPI
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you mark this as the right answer would be appreciated, thanks!